# Re-express this R function in terms of built in ones?

Tags: r, vectorization

Suppose we have a series of sentinel values in `[i,j]` inclusive (call them `y1`) and a vector of values `i:j` (call it `y2`). For example:

```
y1 <- c(649, 652, 656, 658, 660, 661, 669, 671)
y2 <- 649:671
```

Or

```
y1 <- c(719, 725, 726, 728, 729, 731, 734, 740)
y2 <- 718:740
```

No consider this function:

```
Cody5 <- function(y1, y2){
    y3 <- rep(NA, length(y2))
    j <- 1
    i <- 0
    while(j < length(y1)){
        i <- i + 1
        if(y2[i]<y1[j]){
            y3[i]<-y1[j]
        } else {
            y3[i]<-y1[j<-j+1]   
            
        }
    } 
    if(i < length(y3)){
        for(l in i:length(y3)){
            y3[l] <- y1[j]
        }
    }
    y3
}
```

I have been trying to replace `Cody5` using `cut()` but I can't seem to get it right.

## Edit:

I should have wrote it: the sentinel values (`y1`) and the entries of the original vector *are* sorted.

Comment: Please explain what this function does. You can always implement it with Rcpp (which would be trivial here).

Comment: @Roland: yes, that [Rccp it] is what I'm doing now (but if the community knows of a way to express this using built in function, I'd rather use that)

Comment: Do you mean `y1[findInterval(y2, y1, rightmost.closed=TRUE)+1]` ?

Comment: @jogo: I didn't know of `findInterval. THanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more efficient implementation of your function is:

```
y1[findInterval(y2, y1, rightmost.closed=TRUE)+1]
```

with example data:

```
y1 <- c(649, 652, 656, 658, 660, 661, 669, 671)
y2 <- 649:671
Cody5(y1, y2)
# [1] 652 652 652 656 656 656 656 658 658 660 660 661 669 669 669 669 669 669 669 669 671 671 671
y1[findInterval(y2, y1, rightmost.closed=TRUE)+1]
# [1] 652 652 652 656 656 656 656 658 658 660 660 661 669 669 669 669 669 669 669 669 671 671 671
```

Comment: Ok, maybe vectorize isn't the right expression. I meant decompose in terms of more efficient built in functions (such as cut).

Comment: This one seems faster (the sentinel values *are* sorted).

Answer (score 3):

```
mycut <- function(x, y) {
   x[cut(y, c(-Inf, x), 
          labels = FALSE, right = FALSE, 
          include.lowest = TRUE)]
}

y1 <- c(649, 652, 656, 658, 660, 661, 669, 671)
y2 <- 649:671

all.equal(Cody5(y1,y2), 
          mycut(y1,y2))
#[1] TRUE

y1 <- c(719, 725, 726, 728, 729, 731, 734, 740)
y2 <- 718:740

all.equal(Cody5(y1,y2), 
          mycut(y1,y2))
#[1] TRUE
```